# Collide object of a group with the rest of that group

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

In my space shooter game I have asteroids floating around the game area at random. These asteroids are part of the same physicsGroup. I'm using arcade physics. I'd like to be able to check for collisions between an asteroid of that group, and the rest of the group.

I tried the following in my update function:

```
game.physics.arcade.collide(asteroid, asteroids, asteroidCollision, null, this);
game.physics.arcade.collide(asteroids, asteroids, asteroidCollision, null, this);
game.physics.arcade.collide(asteroids);
game.physics.arcade.collide(this.asteroids, this.asteroids);
```

spawnAsteroid function (Omitted the parts regarding spawn position)

```
asteroid = asteroids.create(x, y, 'asteroid');
asteroid.body.setSize(150, 150, 80, 50);
asteroid.body.immovable = true;
asteroid.body.bounce.set(1);
asteroid.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
this.game.physics.arcade.moveToXY(asteroid, this.game.world.randomX,this.game.world.randomY, game.rnd.integerInRange(30, 50));
```

I got no issues with colliding the asteroids group with other sprites or groups, just with themselves.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/28391544/11912 Answer includes a link to the official examples page as well: http://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/group-vs-self

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work, I'll add it to my question.

Comment: Actually I found the reason why, body.immovable was the culprit. It worked with using .collide(asteroids) after removing it. I can accept your comment if u post it as an answer.

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the official examples page for one that shows [how to allow collisions within a group](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/group-vs-self).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28393409/11912) to a similar question has a bit more information as well.